# Query Cosmos DB for all partitions

Tags: .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am thinking of creating a reporting tool for a Cosmos DB instance in our system. I want to discover all the partition keys and the number of items stored for each. I think I should be using pkranges but do not seem to be able to find any examples of how this should work. Any suggestions?

Comment: "Select Distinct" seems to be the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to get list of pkranges using this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/get-partition-key-ranges)

As of now, there is no api to return list of partition keys. There was a feature request at [Azure Cosmos DB Improvement Ideas](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/38737903-method-to-get-all-partitionkeys-of-a-collection-c), but it is declined.

So, you can try "SELECT distinct c.partitionKey FROM c" to get list of distinct partition keys.

Comment: What I have ended up doing is "select distinct c.partitionkey from c" and then loop over that and query for each partition and log its count. that is all I wanted so job done.